# C# Replace String.Split

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I have a string with this format "10,2/20,5/50,3"

Those are wins of every player.
"roomPrize,wins/nextRoomPrize,wins" etc

I figured out how to read it but I want to change the amount of wins for some roomPrize. I've come this far.

```
winsRawData = getStatW.text; //That is the wins string formated as explained above

string[] winSplits = winsRawData.Split('/');

for(int i = 0; i < winSplits.Length; i++)
{
    if(winSplits[i].Split(',')[0] == room.ToString()) //room is the roomPrize that i want to affect
    {
        //newWins is the new win count that I want to update with
        //winSplits[i].Split(',')[1] == newWins;  <-- I just need to do that
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So, what's stopping you?

Comment: [stringly typed code](https://www.bing.com/search?q=stringly+typed+code) is well know pattern (ok, really anty-pattern) and you should not use it. Create a data structure instead and update it directly than convert to string when necessary... For the question itself - you need to show what you expect and why code you have does not work OR ask for what you need to do and use code of example of what you've tried. Post in current state is not meeting SO quality bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question well, you would like to do the following:

```
winSplits[i].Split(',')[1] = newWins;
```

In order to achieve this, you would need to split the value, then re-create it (e.g. Join) and put it back in the original array.
The following should do the trick:

```
winsRawData = getStatW.text; //That is the wins string formated as explained above

string[] winSplits = winsRawData.Split('/');

for (int i = 0; i < winSplits.Length; i++)
{
    var dataArray = winSplits[i].Split(',');
    if (dataArray[0] == room.ToString()) //room is the roomPrize that i want to affect
    {
        // sets the new value.
        dataArray[0] = newWins;
    }

    // finalize by recreating the string and push it back to the original array
    winSplits[i] = String.Join(",", dataArray);
}
```

**Edit** Using the following values:

```
var winsRawData = "10,2/20,5/50,3";
int room = 10;
int newWins = 100;
```

And by adding the `var output = String.Join("/", winSplits);` at the end of the above code, you will get a string output:

```
"100,2/20,5/50,3"
```

See the code below for a complete example:

```
string[] winSplits = winsRawData.Split('/');


for (int i = 0; i < winSplits.Length; i++)
{
    var dataArray = winSplits[i].Split(',');
    if (dataArray[0] == room.ToString()) //room is the roomPrize that i want to affect
    {
        // sets the new value.
        dataArray[0] = newWins.ToString();
    }

    // finalize by recreating the string and push it back to the original array
    winSplits[i] = String.Join(",", dataArray);
}

var output = String.Join("/", winSplits); // = "100,2/20,5/50,3"
```

Comment: Poorly-asked question, but a well-written answer.  +1

Comment: So the final updated string would be all the winSplits combined if I understood well?

Comment: @J.Doe See the edit for a "back to original format" code.

Comment: Yeah that's it, thank you very much and sorry for the poorly asked question.

Answer (score 1):

you should first refactor to deserialize the data into some Player objects, change it's wins count and then serialize it back:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Raw data
            string rawData = "10,2/20,5/50,3";

            // First split
            string[] playersRaw = rawData.Split('/');

            // Initialize a collection for the player objects
            var players = new List<Player>();

            // Iterates over the splitted players data
            foreach (var playerRaw in playersRaw)
            {
                // Deserialize each player 
                var playerDeserialized = Player.Deserialize(playerRaw);

                // Store the player data into the players collection
                if (playerDeserialized != null)
                    players.Add(playerDeserialized);
            }

            // Seeks for player with room prize 10
            foreach (var player in players)
            {
                if (player.RoomPrize == 10)
                    // Increments players data wins count
                    player.Wins += 1;
            }

            // Updates the raw data serializing all players back again
            rawData = string.Join("/", Array.ConvertAll(players.ToArray(), (p) => p.Serialize()));

            Console.WriteLine(rawData);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Player
    {
        public int RoomPrize { get; set; }

        public int Wins { get; set; }

        public static Player Deserialize(string data, char separator = ',')
        {
            Player player = null;
            string[] splittedData = new string[] { };

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) && (splittedData = data.Split(separator)).Length == 2)
            {
                int roomPrize = 0, wins = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(splittedData[0], out roomPrize) && int.TryParse(splittedData[1], out wins))
                {
                    player = new Player();
                    player.RoomPrize = roomPrize;
                    player.Wins = wins;
                }
            }

            return player;
        }

        public string Serialize()
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1}", this.RoomPrize, this.Wins);
        }
    }
}
```

It's much more code, but is easier to maintain.

Comment: Remember to check tags on a question, your answer is a console application while the question is for unity. The logic is right but some usage are wrong (Main method, Console class)

Comment: You're right @Everts, I didn't have noticed the tag, my bad.